# Bounds on the variance of the log of a positive random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, logarithms

Let $X>0$ be a random variable with expectation $E(X)$  and variance $Var(X)$. Can I use this information to get an exact value or upper or lower bounds on the variance of $\log X$?

Comment: As a start, you might consider a uniform distribution on $(0,2)$ against a random variable taking values $1 \pm \frac1{\sqrt{3}}$ with equal probabilities

Comment: Try using the MGF of $Y = \log X$. It is given by $\mathbb{E}[e^{tY}] = \mathbb{E}[X^t]$.You can substitute $t=1$ and $t=2$ and start to get some bounds. This seems viable for the $X>1$ (i.e. $Y>0$) case, but perhaps less so for $X>0$.

Comment: @Henry There are several threads on SE concerning the uniform distribution. I looked at them, but I don't see how they can be extended to the case of non-uniform distributions.

Comment: @AdityaDua Thank you. In my case, I don't have the MGF of Y or X --- only the first two moments of X. However, out of interest, where do you see problems arising for $0<X<1$?

Comment: @AliceSchwarze The MGF is a function of the all the moments. Since you know the first and second moments, you can create upper/lower bounds using the first three terms of the MGF. The other observation to exploit is that the MGF of $Y$, which is by definition $\mathbb{E}[e^{tY}]$ can be written as $\mathbb{E}[X^t]$. If you set $t=1$ or $t=2$, you will get the first and second moments of $X$. I think you can see where I am going with this.